# An error occer when call a Java Stored Procedure in c-treeACE

Tags: java-stored-procedures

When I call a Java Stored Procedure in c-treeACE SQL Explorer, for example: call myProc(), an error happened:

```
Error : -20160    Error Description : Java SP/T Feature not supported.
```

My environment:

- OS: Win 10 64bit
- c-treeACE: V11.0.0 32bit
- JDK/JRE: jdk1.6.0_31 64 bit, or jdk 1.8 64 bit, or jdk 1.6 32 bit
- Also, I have already Setting in ctsrvr.cfg for Java Stored Procedure
  Support(also restart the c-treeACE service):

SETENV  CLASSPATH=D:\Work\Db\d3dxsapi\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar;C:\FairCom\V11.0.0\win32\bin\ace\sql\classes\ctreeSQLSP.jar

SETENV  JVM_LIB=D:\Work\Db\d3dxsapi\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

SETENV  JAVA_COMPILER=D:\Work\Db\d3dxsapi\Java\jdk1_6_0_31\bin\javac.exe

Any one know this, could you please help me? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't know why the error occur. maybe the root cause is about OS environment issue.

Comment: Need help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I used another jdk 1.6(32 bit) to figure it out.